# How to autofill WooCommerce Checkout Address Box

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know there must be a solution to this I just can’t find it.

I want to have when users go to the Checkout page they can either click a button or select a checkbox for a certain predefined address and it will auto fill the address into the Shipping address box.

So meaning the user clicks `<button>` and it auto fills form with 123 Street, NY NY, 11111

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: WC should automatically autofill the address that a returning customer has used before. Otherwise, if the customer is a first-timer or a guest, there's not going to be any data there for the system to autofill from.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved this (kinda)

1. On the Cart & Checkout Page: As I thought I didn't know WooCommerce well enough, so I changed it so now I have a Shipping Zone USA and whithin that I have 2 Shipping Types, the Free Shipment and a Flat Rate to anywhere else
2. On the Checkout Page I set a custom Javascript that when you click the button it auto fills the address in

Inside my functions.php

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wnd_checkout_message', 10 );`

```
function wnd_checkout_message( ) {
    echo '<div class="wnd-checkout-message"><h3>Sending to X? Shipping is free!</h3><button onclick="changeShippingAddr();">Click here to ship</button></div><br />
     ';
```

And then on my actual Checkout Page I have a JavaScript:

```
<script>
function changeShippingAddr(){
document.getElementById("shipping_first_name").value = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;
document.getElementById("shipping_last_name").value = document.getElementById("billing_last_name").value;
document.getElementById("shipping_company").value = "COMPANY";
document.getElementById("shipping_country").value = "COUNTRY";
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
document.getElementById("shipping_state").value = "STATE";
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
document.getElementById("shipping_address_1").value = "ADDR";
document.getElementById("shipping_city").value = "CITY";
document.getElementById("shipping_postcode").value = "ZIP";
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
document.getElementById("select2-shipping_state-container").innerHTML= "State Name";
}
</script>
```

Which essentially sets the Name from Billing to Shipping and inserts a default Address so you don't need to type it in.

Thanks to all the helped out!